# create a set of sets in pyomo based on certain conditions

Tags: set, populate, pyomo, indexed

I am fairly new with Pyomo and I am trying to solve the following problem involving the creation of a set of sets based on certain conditions.

Let assume I have a set O of 'operations' and a set V of 'nodes'. Each operation is associated with a certain list of nodes contained in V.

I would like to create a series of subsets of O based on the condition that they contain a certain specified element x of V.

I was thinking about the following pseudocode to populate an hypotetical subset S.x:

```
create empty set S.x
    for each v in V:
        for each o in O:
           if v is in o:
              populate S.x with operation o
```

However, I am not sure how to formalize that in Pyomo. Do you have any suggestion about which approach to follow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an *indexed* Set:

```
# Assume a dict v_in_o, with keys o and values of a list of v's in that o
model.V = Set(initialize=set(v for o in v_in_o for v in v_in_o[o])
model.O = Set(initialize=v_in_o.keys())
model.S = Set(model.O, within=model.V, initialize=v_in_o)
```

Comment: Yes, perhaps I could try with that. I am not sure whether just defining S like that would handle of the condition that the element should be contained in the original O. Thank you